# Can't access the control in a listview

Tags: asp.net

Can't access the control in a listview

**error**

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

**.cs**

```
public void lnkaddtocart_Command(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
  ((TextBox)ListView_ProductDetails.FindControl("txtbox_pqty")).Visible = false;   
}
```

**.aspx**

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView_ProductDetails">
     <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
     </LayoutTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
              <div class="qty">
                  Qty:
                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtbox_pqty" Text="1" runat="server"/>
                  <input type="hidden" name="product_id" size="2" value="41" />
                       <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkaddtocart" runat="server" 
                            CommandArgument='<%#Eval("pid") %>' 
                            OnCommand="lnkaddtocart_Command"  
                            cssclass="button">
                               <span>Add to Cart</span>
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                  </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `FindControl` on the `NamingContainer` of the `TextBox` which is the [`ListViewItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewitem.aspx) and not the `ListView`. Therefore you can use the `LinkButton's` [`NamingContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx) property to find the [`ListViewItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewitem.aspx).

```
var ctrl = (Control) sender;
var lvi = (ListViewItem) ctrl.NamingContainer;
var txt = (TextBox)lvi.FindControl("txtbox_pqty");
txt.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the textbox in an item template, so there will be multiple textboxes (one for each item). With that said, the Listview won't know which of these textboxes it should fetch.

You'd have to do a find for the textbox on the specific row where the linkbutton was clicked.

For example:

```
public void lnkaddtocart_Command(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    var item = ((Control)sender).NamingContainer as ListViewItem;
    if (item != null)
    {
        ((TextBox)item.FindControl("txtbox_pqty")).Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: OP handles `LinkButton's` `ItemCommand` event not ListView's ItemDataBound.

Comment: @TimSchmelter You are correct, though I only meant to show the OP an example of how *FindControl* is commonly used in a *ListView*, but I could change it to show how to use it in *ItemCommand*.

Comment: I've just mentioned it because that are two totally different events and two different ways to use FindControl(ItemDataBound is already called for every listviewitem implicitely and RowCommand only for that LinkButton). [Not needed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12949829/284240) ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yeah, sorry, should have been more specific. I updated the code example, now using *NamingContainer*.

Answer (score 1):

in addition to "Mario" add the event in your listview like this:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView_ProductDetails" onitemcommand="lnkaddtocart_Command">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="qty">
            Qty:
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtbox_pqty" text='<%#Eval("pid") %>' runat="server" />
            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" size="2" value="41" />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkaddtocart" runat="server" text='<%#Eval("pid") %>' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("pid") %>'
            cssclass="button"><span>Add to Cart</span></asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

CS:

```
public void lnkaddtocart_Command(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txt = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtbox_pqty");
        txt.Visible = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code Inline:**

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView_ProductDetails" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
            OnItemCommand="ListView_ProductDetails_ItemCommand">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div>
                    Qty:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtbox_pqty" Text="1" runat="server" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" size="2" value="41" />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkaddtocart" CommandName="addtocart" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("pid") %>'
                        CssClass="button"><span>Add to Cart</span></asp:LinkButton>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:ListView>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void ListView_ProductDetails_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "addtocart")
        {
            ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtbox_pqty")).Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The control you are looking for actually exists in repeated elements of ListView product details.  To find the control, you'll need to traverse the control hierarchy.

Let's start here, in your method.  First thing to do is get a reference to the ListViewItem that contains your button.  In these .NET event signatures, **sender** refers to the control that raised the event.

```
public void lnkaddtocart_Command(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    // Attempt to cast sender to a LinkButton
    LinkButton originator = sender as LinkButton;

    // Check that we've found it
    if ( originator != null )
    {
       // Now traverse the control hierarchy to get a ListViewItem
       var parentItem = originator.Parent as ListViewItem;

       if ( parentItem != null 
            && parentItem.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
       {
          var textBox = parentItem.FindControl("txtbox_pqty") as TextBox;

          if ( textBox != null )
          {
             textBox.Visible = false;
          }
       }
    }
}
```